# Delays and inaccuracies with Stack Exchange Accounts on the Careers Profiles

Tags: bug, status-completed, reputation, jobs

Randomly checked in on my [Careers profile](http://careers.stackoverflow.com/cv/3179) page today, and noticed that the "Stack Exchange Network" section seems rather out of date, showing me as "Last Seen 2 days ago", and with 11,622 reputation on SO.

However, that was my rep score last week (Tuesday 22 March), which seems like a rather a long delay in updating?

[image: Delay in updating Stack Exchange account information]

Comment: Yep, something's up here.  We'll take a look.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The something that was up is that I'm a doofus.  Should be fixed now (the code, not my being a doofus).  I was requesting users 100 at a time from the API, updating the first 30, dumping the rest, and marking all 100 complete.  YAY!

Again, I'm a doofus.

Doofus.

Comment: It should also be noted that Jason fixed this bug while being away on vacation...beatings will commence on Monday

Comment: *we done been punyoned*

Comment: @Jeff Atwood:  It's `puny0wn3d`.

Comment: @David: I'll see if I can get dear old dad to commence with the beatdown.  It'll be nostalgic for both of us and cathartic for him :)

Comment: @Jason that's...disturbing

Comment: Never mind, it's an easy mistake to make. Thanks.

Comment: @Zhaph: Yeah, *everyone* gets hit by the old off-by-70 bug once in a while, right? :)

Comment: I am still encountering this issue. Also, my last seen date is Jan 1 '00!?

Comment: @Danny: You should be updated now.

Comment: Thanks, it worked. Was it an initial update delay for new account or a bug?

Comment: @Danny: Yes ;-)